# return url when using Spring MVC form based authentication

Tags: spring-mvc

Is it possible in Spring MVC to use return url when configuring form based authentication? For example, user is not authorized and trying to access page /manage, he rederects to login page /account/login?returnurl=%2Fmanage. Then, after he is successfully authorized, he redirects to /manage. As I understand there is no possibility to configure such behaviour in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.configure(HttpSecurity http). Any thoughts on how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Spring MVC does not define any authentication mechanism. Therefore, you can write your own logic and put it in your controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String postLogin(...)
{
    if(user.isAuthenticated)
        return "homepage";
    else
        return "403"
}
```

however, I strongly advice you to rely on a well established framework such as Spring Security. It has everything you need to provide your application with a full functional security layer.
If you decide to go this way, you can leverage the built in login mechanism which will be able to manage every aspect of the authnticatin flow you described.

Let me point you out this [Spring Security Tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-security-tutorials/).